# An everyday object... but it's a Really Obvious Problem Everyday

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, rhyme, acrostic

> None of me and things might fall
>
> Things also can't move, as I recall
>
> Part of me, and you are **me**
>
> All of me, might determine your fate,
>
> After all, you would be under constraint

I am a 4 letter word. Who am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are a

> ROPE

None of me and things might fall

> Ropes hold things up; without, they fall.

Things also can't move, as I recall

> Ropes tie things down.

Part of me, and you are me

> The OP is part of 'rope'

All of me, might determine your fate,

> If you were a criminal, you may be hung on one.

After all, you would be under constraint

> Something tied down with a rope would be constrained. Or perhaps you were 'roped' into something.

Finally:

> Really Obvious Problem Everyday is an acrostic.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Without ropes, it is a really obvious problem everyday :)

Comment: I thought rot13("Cneg bs zr, naq lbh ner zr" vf gnyxvat nobhg ubj vs lbh phg bhg n frtzrag bs n ebcr lbh fgvyy trg n ebcr (n fubegre ebcr vf fgvyy n ebcr))